# How could I make checking user input case-insensitive?

Tags: python

I am adding a few ways of checking user input to my code. Instead of writing `if Answer == ("Yes") or Answer == ("yes")`, is there any way I could make the variable input case-insensitive, so that I don't have to type the word yes twice? Additionally, would there be any way I could make the every variable input option in the line case-insensitive? `if Answer == ("Yes") or Answer == ("yes") or Answer == ("Y") or Answer == ("y"):`.

```
def Repeat():
  Answer = input ("\nDo you want to play again? (Y/N): ")
  if Answer == ("Yes") or Answer == ("yes") or Answer == ("Y") or Answer == ("y"):
    print ("")
  if Answer == ("No") or Answer == ("no") or Answer == ("N") or Answer == ("n"):
    exit()
  if Answer == "Options" or Answer == "options" or Answer == "o" or Answer == "O":
    print ("")
  else:
    print ("Invalid Input")
    Repeat() 
Repeat()
```

Comment: `Answer = input ("\nDo you want to play again? (Y/N): ").lower()`

Comment: I would use `.lower` and `in` like so… `if Answer.lower() in [“yes”, “y”]:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the case of the user input and just check against that:

```
 answer = input("\nDo you want to play again? (Y/N): ").lower()
 if answer in ("yes", "y"):
     ...
```